# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Not Started

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a  SPD 2013 list workflow that automatically starts and emails users when a new item is created. It runs as the user who creates the item. It was working without issue until a few days ago. The workflows wouldn't automatically start and if they were manually started it would throw an error.

After some investigation we discovered that two Service Bus processes had been stopped, so we restarted these. Now the workflows can be manually initiated but always have the status "Not Started" and the Initiator is "Anonymous" as opposed to the user.

Has anyone ever experienced this issue before and could offer any insight? There has been no changes on the server with regards to updates etc...

Comment: Did you solve this issue?